# Variable + $_GET is returning an undefined index error message

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to get a code from a URL. In this case the URL is **http://localhost/proyecto_eltaller/sesionadm.php?ident=1A29A3h5J6K7&buscar=** and the code code is *ident=1A29A3h5J6K7.* As you can see below, I saved it in a variable as $iden = $_GET['ident']; but when I click "despachar" it says:  Undefined index: ident

```
<div class="buscarenc">
<?php
if (isset($_GET['buscar']))
{

    $buscado = $_GET['ident'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM encomiendas WHERE identificador LIKE '$buscado'";
    $resultado = $conexion->query($sql);

    $numfilas = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

    if ($numfilas > 0)
    {
        while ($encontrado = $resultado->fetch_assoc())
        {
            echo $encontrado['identificador'] . "<br>" . "Tipo de encomienda: " . $encontrado['tipo_de_encomienda'] . "<br>" . "Estado de encomienda: " . $encontrado['estado_encomienda'] . "<br>" . "Nombre de quien envía: " . $encontrado['nombre_de_quien_envia'] . "<br>" . "Nombre de destinatario: " . $encontrado['nombre_destinatario'] . "<br>" . "Ciudad de origen: " . $encontrado['ciudad_de_origen'] . "<br>" . "Ciudad de destino: " . $encontrado['ciudad_de_destino'];

        }
         ?>
</div>
       <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="POST"><input type="submit" name="despachar" value="Despachar"> (!)</form>

<?php
    }
    else
    {
        echo "No se encontraron registros para la busqueda.";
    }

?>


<?php   
}   
?>


<?php

if (isset($_POST['despachar']))
{
    $iden = $_GET['ident'];
    $date1 = date("Y/m/d");
    $time1 = date("H:i:s");
    $usuadm1 = $_SESSION['usuario'];
    $sql1 = "UPDATE encomiendas SET estado_encomienda = 'Despachada por $usuadm1 el $date1 a las $time1' WHERE identificador = '$iden'";
    if ($resultado1 = $conexion->query($sql1))
    {

        echo'<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Encomienda despachada");
    </script>';

    }
}

?>
```

Comment: PHP_SELF doesn't carry the previous query string along.

Comment: what should I do to use that code then? I feel that it is very close at hand but I can't get my way to it

Comment: If I use print_r($_SERVER) I'm able to see my ident code there, I just don't know how to get it...